Bayesian updating with affine transformation of random variable
I want to estimate a parameter $\theta$, and I have a prior $\pi(\theta)$. I receive the realization of a random variable $Y$, which has some likelihood $f_Y (y \mid \theta)$. My posterior then satisfies
$$p(\theta \mid y) \propto \pi(\theta) f_Y(y \mid \theta)$$
I know that $Y = aX + b$, where $X$ is another random variable and $a, b$ are known constants and $a \neq 0$. If I were to update my prior with $X$ instead, I would have
$$p(\theta \mid x) \propto \pi(\theta) f_X(x \mid \theta)$$
where $f_X (x \mid \theta)$ is $X$'s likelihood.
My question is: are those two posteriors the same? I think so, but I'm not completely sure my reasoning is correct. It goes as follows:
Since $Y = aX + b$, we have that $f_Y(y) = \frac{1}{a} f_X (x)$. But then updating with $Y$ yields
$$p(\theta \mid y) \propto \pi(\theta) f_Y(y \mid \theta) \propto \pi(\theta) \frac{1}{a} f_X (x \mid \theta) \propto \pi(\theta)f_X (x \mid \theta) \propto p(\theta \mid x) $$
Is this correct?

The posterior distribution is invariant to (deterministic) reparametrizations of the likelihood when the prior distribution is maintained, and the transformation does not depend on the target parameter for inference.
Let $g:\operatorname{supp}\,Y\rightarrow\operatorname{supp}\,X$ be an invertible deterministic transformation, such that $X=g(Y)$ almost surely. Then:
$$
f_X(x\mid\theta) = f_Y(g^{-1}(x)\mid \theta)\cdot\Big|\frac{d}{dx}g^{-1}(x) \Big|
$$
This is proportional to $f_Y(y\mid \theta)=f_Y(g^{-1}(x)\mid \theta)$ when the function $\frac{d}{dx}g^{-1}(x)$ does not depend on $\theta$. This is:
$$
\frac{d}{d\theta}\frac{d}{dx}g^{-1}(x)=0
$$
In your case, $a$ should not be a function of $\theta$.
